# What is the intuition behind "hardness of approximation"?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms

I am reading a paper about graph matching problem. Which is, to some extent, an optimization version of the graph isomorphism problem.

To my surprise, some closely related NP-hard problems are quite different in terms of approximation.

Can anyone give me some intuition behind this phenomenon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202651

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper?

Comment: The question has been asked before on cs.se, and received a very similar answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One important reason why problems that look equally hard to compute exactly might be very different to approximate relates to the fragility of NP-completeness reductions.

The simplest example I can think of the relation between VERTEX COVER and MAX INDEPENDENT SET. The two problems are complementary: given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with a vertex cover $S$, the set $V\setminus S$ is an independent set. This is why it's easy to show that one problem is NP-hard by reduction from the other.

But suppose I can get "close" to a good vertex cover, in that instead of finding the smallest cover $S$, I find a worse cover $S'$ where $|S'| = 2 |S|$. This means that instead of finding the maximum independent set of size $n - |S|$, I've found one of size $n - 2|S|$.

Suppose in this graph the max independent set size was $n/2$. Then essentially my approximation to the vertex cover found nothing at all.

In other words, the NP-hardness reduction only preserved the *exact* solution relationship, not the *approximate* solution relationship.

To preserve approximations, you need a different kind of reduction called an $L$-reduction, and once you limit yourself to such reductions, you realize that the two problems are indeed quite different.

Comment: Thanks! Does harder to approximate implies the problem more local minima?